# "I am the chair of the Economics Department" or "I am chair of the Economics Department"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

While I know in certain contexts a title should not be preceded by the definite article, e.g. "He was elected president," I find myself in doubt whether to use the definite article in such a sentence:

> My name is John Doe. I am (**the**) chair of the Economics Department.

My intuition tells me both are correct. And as far as I have searched on Google, it seems both are used. Is that the case? Any difference in meaning? What about this sentence:

> As (**the**) chair of the Economics Department, I wish to congratulate Jane Doe.

Comment: Both are fine. It's quite conversational and understandable to hear that somebody is *chair of the department* without the leading article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "the" is required:

> My name is John Doe. I am the chair of **the** Economics Department.

This would be incorrect:

> My name is John Doe. I am the chair of Economics Department.

"Economics department" is a specific singular noun (there is only one), so the article "the" is required.  As an aside, if John Doe went to a scholastic conference where there were many different department chairs from many universities, he might introduce himself as:

> My name is John Doe. I am the chair of **an** Economics Department.

"The" is not required in this sentence, but it would not be incorrect to include it:

> As *the* chair of the Economics Department, I wish to congratulate Jane Doe.

You might include "the" before a title in this way to emphasize the title.  For example, "I am **THE** President of the United States."

Comment: I accidentally put the parentheses outside the wrong article in the first sentence. Yes, of course it should be "**the** Economics Department". No question there.